# Template is missing after closing ssh terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-11.10

A simple rails project on a ubuntu server 11.10, I ssh to the server, the project works well. But after I close the ssh terminal, a "Template is missing" error appears.

I run the project with command,

> sudo nohup rails rails s &

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command instead:

```
rails server -d
```

Also, read [Template is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495046/template-is-missing)